# Erro of Configuration - Spring Security 4 with Spring Data in a JavaEE Project with JSF and CDI

Tags: java, spring, jsf, spring-security

This is the first time I'm trying to configure Spring security in a project with JSF. I've used Spring MVC and Spring Boot projects and I had no problems.

I'm using some examples I see on the net along with the documentation for Spring Security 4.2.1.RELEASE itself

**I'm having dependency injection error:**

> No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

**I already reported the ComponentScan annotation and it did not work**

**Tecnologias usadas:**

- Spring Security 4.2.1.RELEASE (spring-framework-bom 4.3.5.RELEASE)
- Spring Data Hopper-SR6 (spring-data-releasetrain)
- CDI
- JSF
- Hibernate
- WildFlay 10

**WebSecurityConfig.class**

```
package com.sgr.config;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private AppUserDetailService userDetailsService;

    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        final DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login.xhtml", "/javax.faces.resource/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login.xhtml");
    }
}
```

**SecurityWebApplicationInitializer.class**

```
package com.sgr.config;

import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

**AppUserDetailService.class**

```
package com.sgr.security;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.sgr.domain.Usuario;
import com.sgr.repositorio.IRepositorioUsuario;

public class AppUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Inject
    private IRepositorioUsuario usuarioRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if (usuario == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Nenhum Usuário encontrado!");
        }else {
            return new UsuarioSistema(usuario, getGrupos(usuario))  ;
        }

    }

    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrupos(Usuario usuario) {
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> grupos = usuarioRepository.findByNameGrupoPermissao(usuario.getLogin());
        grupos.forEach(s -> authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+s)));
        return authorities;
    }
}
```

**IRepositorioUsuario.class**

```
public interface IRepositorioUsuario extends CrudRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    public Usuario findByLogin(String login);

    @Query("SELECT grp.nome FROM Usuario usr, Permissao per, GrupoPermissao grp "
            + "WHERE usr.login = ? AND per.codigo = usr.codigo AND grp.codigo = per.codigo")
    public List<String> findByNameGrupoPermissao(String Login);

}
```

**Usuario.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TUSUARIO")
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5427866189669150032L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long codigo;
    @NotBlank(message="Campo Nome não pode ser vazio!")
    private String nome;
    @NotBlank(message="Campo Login não pode ser vazio!")
    private String login;
    @NotBlank(message="Campo Senha não pode ser vazio!")
    private String senha;
    @Column(name="DATACAD")
    private Date dataCadastro;
    private Boolean situacao;

// get and set...
```

**UsuarioSistema.class**

```
public class UsuarioSistema extends User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Usuario usuario;

    public UsuarioSistema(Usuario usuario, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(usuario.getLogin(), usuario.getSenha(), authorities);
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }
}
```

**LoginBean.class**

```
@Named(value="loginBean")
@SessionScoped
public class LoginBean extends AbstractBean {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private FacesContext facesContext;

    @Inject
    private HttpServletRequest request;

    @Inject
    private HttpServletResponse response;

    private String login;

    public void preRender() {
        if ("true".equals(request.getParameter("invalid"))) {
            addError(true, "Usuário ou senha inválido!", null);
        }
    }

    public void login() throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/login.xhtml");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

**Login.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
  <h:head>
    <title>Login Restaurante Web</title>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="bootstrap" name="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="dist" name="css/AdminLTE.min.css"/>

  </h:head>
  <h:body class="hold-transition login-page">

    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="dummy" />
        <f:event listener="#{loginBean.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
    </f:metadata>

    <div class="login-box">
      <div class="login-logo">
        <a><b>Restaurante</b>WEB</a>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <p:messages id="messages" closable="true"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="login-box-body">
        <p class="login-box-msg">Bem Vindo!</p>
        <h:form id="formLogin">
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <p:inputText pt:autocorrect="off"
                         pt:spellcheck="false"
                         pt:autocomplete="off"
                         pt:autocapitalize="off"
                         styleClass="form-control"                          
                         placeholder="Login"
                         id="login" value="#{loginBean.login}"/>
            <span class="fa fa-user form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group has-feedback">
            <p:password pt:autocorrect="off"
                        pt:spellcheck="false"
                        styleClass="form-control"                         
                        placeholder="Senha"/>
            <span class="fa fa-lock form-control-feedback"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <button type="submit" 
                      jsf:update="@form,messages"
                      jsf:process="@form"
                      class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat"
                      jsf:action="#{loginBean.login()}" >
                  Login
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div align="center" class="col-xs-12">
                  <i class="fa fa-hand-o-right"></i>
                  <span class="text-bold">
                      <a href="#">Esqueci minha Senha</a>
                  </span>
              </div>
          </div>        
        </h:form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h:outputScript library="plugins" name="jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"/>
    <h:outputScript library="bootstrap" name="js/bootstrap.min.js"/>
  </h:body>
</html>
```

**Log_ERRO**

```
20:12:46,453 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
20:12:46,747 WARN  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
20:12:46,751 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 35 more

20:12:46,754 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sgr: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./sgr: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:85)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:236)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:100)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:552)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:200)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:171)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:234)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.sgr.security.AppUserDetailService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1064)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

you should add `Component` Annotation in the class AppUserDetailService. ComponentScan means that spring will provide a bean instance for the class which have Component Annotation.

Comment: Is the AppUserDetailService in the child package of ComponentScan? If not, you should set basePackage in ComponentScan